# What is the use of having canonical names in computer networks? Can't we just use alias names to get IP address directly?

Tags: dns

For eg. we wanted to search google.com (let us think that its an alias name), then we will lookup in DNS and get its canonical name which further helps to get the IP address. Why cant we just get IP address from alias name as it would also be unique.

Comment: Your question is unclear as is and off topic here as not related to programming. You might want to read an introduction on DNS, and about the `A`/`AAAA` and `CNAME` records.

Answer (score 0):

It is not always guaranteed that `alias name` resolves to same IP address. And, there is a very good reason for it. Lets say person A is browsing `google.com` from country A. Google has it servers all over the world (for efficiency purposes). It is beneficial if person A requests are directed towards google servers in country A than towards some other distant location. Here where `CNAME` records comes into the picture. `CNAME` records are configured in such a way that google.com resolves to servers which are specific to country A. And another case where you get different IP for same alias name is when you fetch `MX` records (mail server records), for the same domain you can have different servers managing mails and web traffic.

Answer (score 0):

The design of URL is for convenience. The convenience is that when we want to change the server IP, we don't need to tell all the users the new ip of the website. In other words, what we have done in server will make no change to users. That is the core thought in server design.